# При подгрузке контента ajax не удаляется старый блок

Tags: jquery, ajax

В чем вопрос: у меня при загрузке контента **без обновления страницы**, загружаемый блок(*.right-col*) добавляется в старый блок- .right-col, div на странице где произошел переход. Суть такова, что старый контент должен удалиться и подгрузиться новый - без вложенности блоков.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#to-catalog').click(function () {
    if ($(window).width() < 1023) {

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' .right-col';
        console.log(toLoad);
        $('.right-col').hide('fast', loadContent);
        function loadContent() {
            // $('#ajax-wrap').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());
            // $('.left-col.hidden_tablet_sidebar').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());
            $('.right-col').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            // $('#ajax-wrap').show('normal');
            // $('.left-col.hidden_tablet_sidebar').show('normal');
            $('.right-col').show('normal');
        }

        return false;
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/catalog';
    }

});
```

});
[image: screen]

Comment: "_Load data from the server and **place** the returned HTML **into** the matched **element**._" что вам не понятно из этой строки документации к методу `load()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Как следует из описания метода [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) она загружает контент, и вставляет его внутрь селектора, к которому был применен.

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML **into** the
>   matched element.

Если вам необходимо заменить внутренности селектора, то вы можете использовать метод [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) и загрузить данные с помощью обычного ajax `post`-запроса (или `get`, но `load` использует `post`)

```
$.post(toLoad, function(content){
    $(".right-col").replaceWith(content);
    //showNewContent();
});
```

Останется вопрос анимации, пришедший контент вряд ли будет содержать классы или стили, отвечающие за то, что он будет скрыт. Поэтому заменится и отобразиться сразу без анимаций.

Другим вариантом будет несколько изменить структуру html, чтобы заменялись действительно только внутренности. Это также решит вопрос с текущим состоянием скрытия-отображения `.right-col`.